# Print content of a hash map in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml, hashtable

What is the simplest way to print the Content of a hash table in Ocaml? I'm new to Ocaml and everything I saw untill now Looks pretty much complicated. 
To exemplify, if we produce a simple hash table like this:

```
# let ht = Hashtbl.create 100;;
# Hashtbl.add ht "x" "a";
  Hashtbl.add ht "x" "b";
  Hashtbl.add ht "y" "c";;
```

I would like to print out like this:

```
# print_hash ht;;
```

And then get the following result:

x: a, b

y: c

I guess I have to use the Marshal module, but don't really know exactly how
because using the to_string Option the result is not something readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple trick consists in using `Hashtbl.iter` :

```
 Hashtbl.iter (fun x y -> Printf.printf "%s -> %s\n" x y) ht;;
```

The function given has first argument expects 2 arguments which are the key and the value.

Comment: Note that due to how hashtables work, you would get `x -> b`. The `a` value gets overwritten.

Comment: in Ocaml, Hashtbl can have multiple entries with the same key value - like the example written by J. Abe.

Comment: I just tried, and it is not the case; Returns both values, a and b, this is the command Output:

Comment: # Hashtbl.iter (fun x y -> Printf.printf "%s -> %s\n" x y) ht;;
y -> c
x -> b
x -> a

Comment: My bad, I'm always confusing the behavior with maps.

Answer (score 1):

This works, assuming key and value are strings:

```
# let open BatInnerIO in
  BatHashtbl.print write_string write_string stdout ht;;
```

This prints a rather neatly formatted string:

```
{
Key1: Value1,
Key2: Value2
}
```

If your key and/or value type are not string, you can use other printers from [BatInnerIO](https://ocaml-batteries-team.github.io/batteries-included/hdoc2/BatIO.html), such as `write_i64` to write down an `int64`, and so on.

Printing to `stderr` is also possible.

Comment: Once is the Batteries library installed, it works perfectly.